# u'Too' u'much' u'unicode' u'returned'

Tags: python, json, web-services, unicode

I have an api which I'm putting things into and out of in a natural language processing context, using json.

*Everything* is coming out as unicode. For example, if retrieve a list of words from my api, every single word is u''. This is what the json output looks like after printing to a file:

```
{u'words': [u'every', u'single', u'word']}
```

I must clarify that in the terminal everything looks good, just not when I print the output to a file.

I haven't figured out yet if this is preferable default behavior or if I need to do something along the way to make this plain, or what. The outputs are going to used with languages other than python, other contexts where they need to be readable and/or parseable.

So clearly I don't have a grasp on python & unicode and how and where this is being.

1. Is this preferable when dealing with json? Should I not worry about it?
2. How I turn this off, or how do I take an extra step (I've already tried but can't figure out exactly where this is doing this) to make this less of a nuisance.

I have much to learn, so any input is appreciated.

EDIT: all the input has been useful, thank you.

I was under the mistaken notion that jsonify did more than it actually does I guess. If I do json.dumps earlier in my task chain, I get actual json on the other end.

Comment: That's supposed to be JSON? Then yes, you should worry about it. How are you converting your list of words to JSON?

Comment: Strings in JSON are unicode, so that's to be expected: *"A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters [...]"*. http://json.org/

Comment: Your only problem is that you're `print`ing dicts and lists, instead of only strings and unicodes. When you do this, the `repr` of each object in the dict/list is shown, and unicode objects will be shown with a leading `u`. If you only print things that are meant to be printable, they'll display correctly.

Comment: right now the output of my functions is going through flask's jsonify on return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this, and you don't need to do anything about it.

In Python 2, a `str` is similar to a C string - it's just a sequence of bytes, sometimes incorrectly assumed to be ASCII text. It can contain *encoded* text, e.g. as UTF-8 or ASCII.

The `unicode` type represents an actual string of text, similar to a Java `String`. It is text in the abstract sense, not tied to a particular encoding. You can decode a `str` into `unicode`, or encode a `unicode` into a `str`.

JSON keys and values are strings - they are not byte arrays, but text - so they are represented by `unicode` objects in Python.

If you need JSON output for use in another language, use the `json` module to produce it from your dictionary:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({u'words': [u'every', u'single', u'word']})
{"words": ["every", "single", "word"]}
```

Comment: This is basically it, I dump the output to json before passing it to jsonify in flask and it is good.

Answer (score 3):

It is preferable, yes, since JSON is defined to be unicode.

If you have more specific things that are causing you trouble you should share them, otherwise I'd recommend watching [Ned Batchelder's Intro](http://bit.ly/unipain) if you're just generally uncomfortable with Unicode (in Python in particular). I don't know what is causing this to be a nuisance to you, since I don't know what you're doing with this dict.

Comment: It only is a nuisance on the other end when I print output to a file, where presumably it should not be in any python form, strictly json, otherwise everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep everything internal to python in unicode if there's any chance you will need it.  Where python speaks to other programs, use `s.encode('UTF-8')` to make a regular string that you can write to a file or socket or whatever.  Use `s.decode('UTF-8')` to convert a string from a file/socket back to unicode.  (UTF-8 seems like a reasonable default, but use whatever your protocol specifies.)